# SFML CMAKE issue with finding sfml-system

Tags: cmake, sfml

I'm on macos, and for whatever reason, when I try CMake with SFML, it looks for sfml-system in the wrong location. Here is the error I'm gettin

```
CMake Error at /Library/Frameworks/SFML.framework/Versions/2.6.0/Resources/CMake/SFMLSharedTargets.cmake:144 (message):
  The imported target "sfml-system" references the file

     "/Library/Frameworks/SFML.framework/Versions/./sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.0/sfml-system"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/Library/Frameworks/SFML.framework/Versions/2.6.0/Resources/CMake/SFMLSharedTargets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Library/Frameworks/SFML.framework/Versions/2.6.0/Resources/CMake/SFMLConfig.cmake:116 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

This happens even when I don't reference sfml-system in my cmake file.

I've tried deleting the cache & cmakefiles directories.

I've tried removing the frameworks from library/frameworks and adding them back in, didn't do anything.

I've tried removing any references to sfml-system & making my cmake file the bare minimum

I'm kind of stumped honestly.

Comment: "I've tried removing the frameworks from library/frameworks and adding them back in" - Do you mean that you have removed SFML from your system and have re-**installed** it? How exactly have you installed SFML?

Comment: Yeah pretty much that. It was searching for the frameworks in my library/frameworks folder in my mac and I was pretty sure the way to install sfml was to just drag and drop the frameworks into the frameworks folder.

I also installed it through homebrew just in case

Comment: "I was pretty sure the way to install sfml was to just drag and drop the frameworks into the frameworks folder." - Well, this could be the very reason of the error you got. And the error message describes it: `* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.`. "I also installed it through homebrew just in case" - So, whether the file `/Library/Frameworks/SFML.framework/Versions/2.6.0/Resources/CMake/SFMLSharedTargets.cmake` belongs to that installation? I am pretty sure that homebrew provides a way for check that.

Comment: I figured out that my issue was the frameworks installation. Now I'm able to compile on cmake but when I actually make it can't find any of the sfml library files

Comment: "it can't find any of the sfml library files" - This seems to be an another problem, so it should be asked in **separate question**. When ask it, make sure to provide the **code** and the **exact error message**.